# VSCode file search keeps searching endlessly

Tags: ssh, vscode-remote

I've tried to set up VSCode to be able to edit website files instead of having to use cPanel File Manager. To do so, I got the SSH FS extension, set up my remote ssh configurations and successfully got connected to the target folder. I then added the folder as a workspace. Everything else is fine, I can access files and edit them, but I can't seem to search either

1. files by their names using CMD + P, or
2. search within files using CMD + SHIFT + F

What I see is just the search animation endlessly. If I click on "Search in Open Editor" toggle and turn it on, I can search using both 1) and 2) just fine.

I've tried a lot of different solutions including:

1. Trying latest VSCode Insider in hope that this bug got fixed at some point in the recent past
2. Trying turning the "exclude file" off and on in case it was causing issues with the search
3. Trying entering specific regex for the folder I want to search a file in the search method 2.

Some helpful explanations I've read around the internet are

1. VSCode is trying to search for files within the whole filesystem, and that there are too many files to search. I doubt this might be the issue given that I've set the root folder in my ssh connection to "~/public_html/SkyHighMS" and the file system is certainly not very big, at most ~50 files with an average ~300 lines of code.
2. This is a bug that was reported to be fixed on VSCode official community forum.

[Search in files broken on SSH remote target](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74863572/search-in-files-broken-on-ssh-remote-target)

https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/108102

https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/179121